# PowerBI App Owns Data Application - Scope Doesn't Exist

Tags: powerbi, azure-api-apps, azure-app-registration

I am attempting to launch a power bi 'app owns data' client application and am getting an error related to the Scope I added within the Expose an API area for my client application.  I created a custom scope called Reports.Embed and believe I have configured it correctly but when I attempt to login to the application I get an error saying.

**AADSTS65005: The application 'api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' asked for scope 'Reports.Embed' that doesn't exist.**

The application asking for the scope is my admin app.  Both the admin app and the client app are set up for access only to my organization.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Expose An API]
[image: API Permissions]